# Set KeyBinding on a whole WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, key-bindings

I working on an MVVM window and want to control something in the view model by the keyboard, but if i place the following code directly under the window it can't be compiled only if i place under for example a text box. How can i do this?

```
   <KeyBinding Key="P" Command="{Binding ToggleCommand}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the `KeyBinding` to the `InputBindings` property on `Window`

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="P" Command="{Binding ToggleCommand}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Comment: How do you make it work for the whole window regardless of what control has focus? This does not work when I am editing a row in a datagrid.